# Number of MRI scanners in the world today?

Tags: statistics, mri, medical-imaging

How many MRI scanners are there today in the whole world? My own search only revealed numbers in certain countries but no overall count.

Comment: Can you share the numbers you have? I am curious. FYI  [MRI scanners in the United States with teslas](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7684/1652)

Comment: Not really health related?

Comment: @jiggunjer  [What is our stance on questions about asking for a specific number?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/610/43)

Comment: @jiggunjer The numbers I have so far are [these](http://www.statista.com/statistics/282401/density-of-magnetic-resonance-imaging-units-by-country/) from which one can calculate the absolute number in certain countries knowing the populations. However, not all countries are listed.

Answer (score 2):

[Magnetic-resonance.org](http://www.magnetic-resonance.org/ch/21-01.html)

> World­wide, there are approximately 36,000 MR machines. At present,
>   about 2,500 MR imaging units are sold worldwide every year

- This [CDC link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/hus/2010/120.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj9z9z77djNAhWk24MKHcpLAOMQFghHMAE&usg=AFQjCNHHP_cU0QGKH00NuHSI1j6yov_sLA) shows the amount per country.

If you take this to be a good reference then this could be answer.

Comment: Nice find(s) :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the statistics given on that site end in 2001. Since 2001, I suppose, much has changed.